# Setting Local Repository in Maven

Tags: maven

I want to add a local Repository to Maven, because i want to use my own archetype for building a maven pom.

One Solution i ve found was to add this to the setting.xml:
/.m2/repository
but it doesn't work.

Has anyone a good solution?

Comment: "<localRepository>C:/Users/mkettner/.m2/repository</localRepository>" sorry for that

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? It is hard to help you without details.

Comment: when i do on command : mvn archetype:generate he download the repo again from maven